# How can I enforce all containers work together with domain localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, localhost

I have 8 frontends apps, 12 backends servers. Frontends are Vue.js or AngularJS, backedends are ASP.NET Core 3.1, and SQL server and Redis and Other services

all services are similar configs for Docker containers, except loggings, ports and so on. they all work in same named network `mynetwork`

```
  abcservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}abcservice
    container_name: abcServer
    hostname: abcservice
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: abcService/Dockerfile
    networks:
        - mynetwork
```

but I have to use `http://host.docker.internal:{portnumer}`, so all containers can work well together. How can I force all apps work together on `http://localhost:{portnumer}`?

let's say a simple ASP.NET core app, if started it **WITHOUT** `docker`, it can access `SQL Server(run in docker)` and `Redis(run in docker)` with domain `http://localhost:port`, but once if start it with `docker`, I have to access the app via domain `http://host.docker.internal:port`, otherwise it cannot reach `SQL` and `Redis`. because inside containers, `localhost` means the container itself, I need something config to let container reach other containers with localhost and specified ports.

Appreciate.

Comment: Have you read through background material like [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)?  Between containers, you should be able to use the Compose service names like `abcservice` as host names; you do not need `container_name:`, `hostname:`, or `networks:` settings.  (And, yes, "in a non-Docker developer environment" and "inside Compose" are different environments and need different settings for questions like "where is Redis".)

Comment: @DavidMaze does it mean that with docker, it's no longer possible to use `localhost` to cross all servers?

Comment: Even without Docker, many times your data stores and dependent services aren't `localhost`; for example, if your Redis is actually AWS Elasticache, it's not `localhost`.  With Docker at least you're pretty sure the other container _isn't_ `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Environment variables

You can either use ports for all services, and use environment variables in a `.env` file to switch between hostnames. The `.env` file works out-of-the-box with Docker Compose, see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

Using ports:

```
ports:
   - 6379:6379
```

Sample `.env` file:

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

## Option 2: using network_mode host

Another option is apply host network settings instead using `network_mode` on each service. That should apply host network settings to a service, instead of running in isolation.

```
network_mode: host
```